# IAR plugins for Eclipse Mars 4.5

Tags: eclipse, iar

In order to use IAR compiler plugins in Eclipse Mars 4.5, I installed the IAR plugin manager in Eclipse Mars 4.5. According to the instructions provided in IAR website plugins were suppose to be installed using the IAR plugin manager in Help tab in Eclipse after the installation of the IAR plugin manager.
However, after the successful installation of the IAR plugin manager, I dont see the Plugin manager in the Help tab column.
Does anyone have any idea as to how to make it work.

Thanks!